# Splitting data received from Arduino

Tags: vb.net

I am new to vb and I'm trying to split serial data received from the Arduino board on Visual Basic. I've watched and followed tutorials online that outputs all the serial data in one textbox and it works. But now i need to split the data into textboxes that correspond to the sensor (i have 5 sensors).

I've tried using .Split and arrays to split and then store the data before moving it to the corresponding textbox but it doesn't work.

Appreciate all the help I can get

```
Dim receivedData As String = ""

Private Sub AirQuality_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    GetSerialPortNames()
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    txtPmax.Text = 14.7
    txtPmin.Text = 10
    txtO2max.Text = 21
    txtO2min.Text = 15
    txtCO2.Text = 1000
    txtP25.Text = 25
    txtP10.Text = 50
    txtCO.Text = 35

End Sub

Sub GetSerialPortNames()
    ' Show all available COM ports.
    For Each sp As String In My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames
        cbCOMPort.Items.Add(sp)
    Next
    cbCOMPort.SelectedIndex = 0
End Sub

Private Sub btnConnect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConnect.Click
    Try
        If (btnConnect.Text = "Connect") Then
            If (cbCOMPort.Text <> "") Then
                'Open Serial Port
                SerialPort1.Close()
                SerialPort1.PortName = cbCOMPort.Text
                SerialPort1.BaudRate = 9600
                SerialPort1.DataBits = 8
                SerialPort1.Parity = Parity.None
                SerialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One
                SerialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None
                SerialPort1.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default 'very important!
                SerialPort1.ReadTimeout = 10000

                SerialPort1.Open()
                btnConnect.Text = "Dis-connect"
                Timer1.Enabled = True

                btnUpdate.PerformClick()

            Else
                MsgBox("Select a COM port first")
            End If
        Else
            SerialPort1.Close()
            btnConnect.Text = "Connect"
            Timer1.Enabled = False

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub

Function ReceiveSerialData() As String
    Dim Incoming As String
    Dim Array() As String
    Incoming = SerialPort1.ReadExisting
    Array = Split(Incoming, ";")
    Pactual.Text = Array(0)
    O2actual.Text = Array(1)
    COactual.Text = Array(2)
    CO2actual.Text = Array(3)
    P25actual.Text = Array(4)
    P10actual.Text = Array(5)
    txtUpdate.Text = Array(6)


End Function

Sub numberValidate()
    Try
        If (CDbl(txtPmax.Text) < CDbl(txtPmin.Text) Or (CDbl(txtO2max.Text) < CDbl(txtO2min.Text))) Then
            MsgBox("Error. Must be numbers or Max < Min")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error. Must be numbers or Max < Min")
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Static bFlash As Boolean
    receivedData = ReceiveSerialData()

    If receivedData IsNot Nothing Then
        txtUpdate.Text = receivedData
        ' Warning in GUI
        Dim bWar As Boolean = receivedData.Contains("--Pressure not OK--" Or "--CO2 not OK--" Or "--O2 not OK--")
        If receivedData.Contains("--Pressure not OK--" Or "--CO2 not OK--" Or "--O2 not OK--") Then
            bFlash = Not bFlash
            If bFlash Then
                txtUpdate.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0)
            Else
                txtUpdate.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255)
            End If

        Else
            txtUpdate.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255)

        End If
        If receivedData.Contains("--Condition: Normal--") Then
            txtUpdate.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255)
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    Dim writeText As String
    writeText = "<" & CDbl(txtPmax.Text).ToString("00.0") & CDbl(txtPmin.Text).ToString("00.0") & CInt(txtO2max.Text).ToString("00") & CInt(txtO2min.Text).ToString("00") & CInt(txtCO2.Text).ToString("0000") & ">"
    txtUpdate.Text = writeText
    SerialPort1.Write(writeText)

End Sub
```

Comment: What format is the input - can we have an example?

Comment: --O2 not OK--
Vout = 1.56 V;
Latitude: 0.000000
Longitude: 0.000000
Temperature: 24.70 C;
Pressure: 14.61Psi;
Altitude: 50.99m;
O2 Concentration: 8.64%;
CO value: 3.12PPM;
CO2: 400PPM;
PM2.5: 5.6ug/m3;
PM10: 7.8ug/m3;

^This is the format for the output on the serial mon of the Arduino

Comment: Have you debugged the `Incoming` content?

Comment: oh yes sorry forgot to include it. the error is "IndexOutofRangeException was unhandled". I've tried googling the error but i don't understand what it means or how to resolve it

Comment: Can you determine which line you get the error on? That error implies that your Split command is providing less than 7 elements.

Comment: It happens on "O2actual.Text = Array(1)" from "Function ReceiveSerialData() As String"

Comment: Set a break point at `Pactual.Text = Array(0)` and then hover your mouse over the `incoming` on the line `Incoming = SerialPort1.ReadExisting` to see what it holds, and if it holds meaningful information, hover over `Array` on the line `Array = Split(Incoming, ";")`. I suspect that it will be because the Arduino hasn't sent enough data. You might want to keep reading data until you have a complete string and then try processing it.

Comment: Small tip on using sttackoverflow - If you want a particular user to see your comment add their username after an @ symbol and with no spaces e.g. @DavidWilson. That way, the user well get a notification. Otherwise we probably wont see it unless we keep checking back to the question.